# how to add windows 7 ribbons to a WTL app

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, ribbon, wtl

Has anybody tried to use the native windows 7 ribbon control in a WTL app?

I mean the control behind:

```
#include <UIRibbon.h>
```

or an example for the MFC. (i don't talk about the ribbons from the MFC Feature Pack!)

--- Sven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/RibbonUI.aspx